# OSX 10.6 + OSX 10.7 + WIN XP?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

I am running 10.6 on my macbook pro and purchased a while ago 10.7 and also have a purchased copy of Windows XP

I am using a software which requires me to use Windows XP which i want to use with Boot Camp, my only problem is that i need to use the Boot Camp version on OSX 10.6 that supports Windows XP and not from later OSX versions.

I would like to reinstall the entire system and install in order which will allow me to have working copies of 10.6 for boot amp installation + a working copy of 10.7 (later to be upgraded to 10.9) and a working copy of Windows XP.

> My plan for re-installation:
>   (250MB DRIVE)
>   Clean install OSX 10.6 
>   -> Partition: "Macintosh HD" Leave 50GB for OSX 10.6 > "Macintosh HD 2" 150GB for OSX 10.7 >"Windows HD" 50 GB for Windows XP
>   ->Clean install OSX 10.7
>   -> Going back to 10.6 > run Boot Camp and install Windows XP on "Windows HD"

It will be very important for me to upgrade "Macintosh HD 2" 150GB with OSX 10.7 later on to OSX 10.9 (verified that it will work on this machine) and I do not want to mess up the "Windows HD" with Windows XP...

How do I install things so I can make sure OSX 10.7 will load by default?

Answer (score 1):

You should do it in these order:

- partition drive into two partitions — first for 10.7 and second for 10.6 and XP combined
- install 10.7
- install 10.6
- run Bootcamp Assistant and install xp
  — Choose 10.7 partition in Startup Disk in System Preferences

And if you only need 10.6 for Bootcamp assistant you may skip that because 10.7 has it. Once everything is set, use the Startup Disk control to write the Lion OS as the default for power on.